# Layout for suggested items for Autocompletetext View

Tags: java, android, layout, autocompletetextview

If I have an AutocompletetextView with a width of 50dp and next to it a button, then the layout with the suggested items will also have the width of 50dp, below these two items. Is it possible to have the width of the suggested items layout fill_parent for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"` attribute.

Comment: cheers for the answer! It works :) Didn't think it was that easy.